# Number of generators for the Schur multiplier of a finite group

Tags: homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $M(G)=H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ be its Schur multiplier. Are there any known bounds on the number of generators of $M(G)$ in terms of $G$? For example, if $G$ is abelian of rank $r$, then $M(G)$ can be  generated by $r(r-1)/2$ elements. Is there anything that can be said for more general finite groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a finite group has a presentation with $g$ generators and $r$ relations, then the Schur multiplier is generated by $r-g$ elements. There's been lots of work studying groups and presentations where this is minimal ("efficient" presentations and groups).

Comment: Would you please give the reference to this result?

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. It's very old and well-known, and I think it goes back to Schur. A slightly more modern reference: D.L. Johnson and E.F. Roberston, "Finite groups of deficiency zero" in Homological Group Theory (ed. C.T.C. Wall), C.U.P., 1979. But Googling "deficiency efficient Schur" will give lots of other references.

Comment: One should read "If a **finite** group has a presentation with ...". A general bound for an arbitrary finitely presented group has been obtained by D. Epstein (1961) who gives much of the credits to P. Hall (the bound on the number of generators is enlarged by adding the free rank of the abelianization of $G$, see lemma 1.2 of "Finite presentations of groups and 3-manifolds"). Epstein cites I. Schur (1904) and B. H Neumann (1956) as the authors/finders of early work on the relation between the Schur multiplier and the deficiency of a group.

Comment: @LucGuyot Thanks. I've edited my answer to correct that.